# How do I check if it's the homepage in a Plone website using ZPT?

Tags: python, plone, zope, template-tal, zpt

I want to change my website's header only it if's not the homepage. Is there a *tal:condition* expression for that?

I've been reading [this](http://plone.org/documentation/tutorial/zpt) and can't find what I'm looking for...

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to use two really handy plone views that are intended just for this purpose. The interface that defines them is at https://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.app.layout/trunk/plone/app/layout/globals/interfaces.py, in case you want to check it out.

```
<tal:block
   tal:define="our_url context/@@plone_context_state/canonical_object_url;
               home_url context/@@plone_portal_state/portal_url;"
   tal:condition="python:our_url == home_url">
HERE GOES YOUR STUFF
</tal:block>
```

The great thing about @@plone_context_state and @@plone_portal_state is that they handle all sorts of weird edge cases. context/@@plone_context_state/canonical_object_url also returns the right, most basic, object's url even when you're viewing the default page in the portal root with a query string appended :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar to ax:

```
<tal:block define="global currentUrl request/getURL" condition="python: u'home' not in str(currentUrl)">

<!-- whatever -->

</tal:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like `<tal:condition="python: request.URLPATH0 == '/index_html'` ...>`? see [TALES Built-in Names](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/source/AppendixC.html#built-in-names) and the [Zope API Reference](http://www.zope.org/Documentation/Books/ZopeBook/2_6Edition/AppendixB.stx) for more choices.